# Downloading files in Android

Tags: android, service

Is it possible to create a service that would work with notifications, meaning that when there is a notification from the server, the service receives this notification, and then performs an action in the background without user interaction, in particular, downloads a file from server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

In many different ways and with the use or not of many different services.

One commonly known is the way `Play Store` works when install application by the web-site.

You can read about:

- [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)
- [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)
- [Download Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html)
- [Transferring Data Using Sync Adapters](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html)